# What is the difference between Nuance Dragon v13 Premium and Nuance Dragon v14 Individual?

Tags: speech-recognition

What is the difference between Nuance Dragon v13 Premium and Nuance Dragon v14 Individual?

Havent found a product page on nuance, but there are sales on amazon.

Comment: You didn't look very hard. http://www.nuance.com/ucmprod/groups/corporate/@web-enus/documents/collateral/dns13_pro-pre-homefeatures.pdf compares the features for the different versions of v13.

Comment: You didn't look very hard. That document compares different versions of version 13, legal professional, premium and home. There is nothing about the version 14 Individual I was asking.

Comment: Maybe not (note we are not here to research for you) but it's a good starting point for **your own research**. You could, for example, ask their support (http://www.nuance.com/support/dragon-naturallyspeaking/index.htm#dr_support_contact) as there doesn't appear to be any documentation on their website about v14. I would imagine that "individual" is the same as "home" apart from v13 -> v14 differences.

Comment: http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask says: "**Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question?** Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"

Comment: This kind of comparison questions often don't get much positive attention, unfortunately. There is a proposal for a Stack Exchange website dedicated to it http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93761/software-comparisons

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of new features with v14 http://www.nuance.com/products/help/dragon/dragon-for-pc/enx/professionalgroup/main/Content/WhatsNew/new_v14.htm. Nuance does not claim v14 to be more accurate than v13 for everyday speech to text functions. So, it may not be worth paying for the upgrade unless you want the new features. They don't seem all that impressive for the extra money.

Some of the new features include,

- auto-text commands
- windows 10 & office 2016 support
- improved transcription accuracy for recorded sources (not live)